# Overload template member function over any container of A or B

Tags: c++, templates, containers, template-specialization

I have 2 existing classes A and B. I want to implement a third struct C such that C implement operator() which would take any container of A or *using a different implementation* any container of B. Is it possible to do a such thing using template specialization ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`enable_if` is very useful in lots of scenarios, but in cases like these I'm usually more inclined to use tag dispatching. To my eye, the code looks cleaner, behaves more predictably, and if you try to use it wrongly, the error messages make slightly more sense.

```
struct C
{
    template <class T>
    void operator()(const T& container) const
    {
        operator()(container, Tag<typename T::value_type>());
    }

private:
    template <class V> struct Tag {};

    template <class T>
    void operator()(const T& container, Tag<A>) const
    {
        std::cout << "A\n";
    }

    template <class T>
    void operator()(const T& container, Tag<B>) const
    {
        std::cout << "B\n";
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<A> a;
    std::list<B> b;
    C c;
    c(a);
    c(b);
}
```

Comment: Great suggestions from everyone. I like this one best because of the reasons mentioned in the first few lines.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using template template parameters.

Assuming your containers have two parameters (content type and allocator):

```
class A {};
class B {};

struct C {
  template <
    template <
      typename,
      typename
    >
    class V
  >
  void operator()(const V<A, std::allocator<A> >& /* ca */) const {
  }

  template <
    template <
      typename,
      typename
    >
    class V
  >
  void operator()(const V<B, std::allocator<B> >& /* cb */) const {
  }
};
```

Which would then allow you to do the following:

```
int main() {
  std::vector<A> va;
  std::vector<B> vb;

  std::list<A> la;
  std::list<B> lb;

  C c;

  c(va);
  c(la);

  c(vb);
  c(lb);
}
```

Comment: Merci ! I accept the solution of user2079303 thought since it support really *any* container and could be useful in other situations.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it should be possible. Arkanosis has a good solution but here is if you want to use template specialization:

```
class A {};
class B {};

template <template <typename , typename > class Z, class Elem> struct C
{    
    void operator()(const Z<Elem, std::allocator<Elem>>& v) {   std::cout << "General implement" << std::endl; }
};

template <template <typename, typename > class Z> struct C<Z,B>
{    
    void operator()(const Z<B, std::allocator<B>>& v) {   std::cout << "Specialized implement" << std::endl; }
};
```

Then some client code:

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <vector>
    using namespace std;
    int main(int argc, char** argv) 
    {
    std::vector<A> as;
    std::list<B> bs;
    C<vector,A> ca;
    ca(as);
    C<list,B> cb;
    cb(bs);
    }
```

If you want to handle different container types from the same `C`-style class you can derive from templates of the C struct e.g. `class MultiContainerHandlerForA : public C<vector,A>, public C<list,A>`.

Comment: ps : In fact, I dont need the allocator template parameter.

Comment: Errare. You can specialize the struct but not the function member (I already encouter this problem). This is not a valid solution.

Comment: Ok I didn't read the end of your answer. There are just too many good answers and I can't decide. :S

Answer (score 1):

Overloads using `std::enable_if` and `std::is_same` seem to work. Not very pretty though. Note that these are c++11 features.

```
struct A {};
struct B {};
struct C {
    template<class Cont>
    void operator()(const Cont& c, typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<typename Cont::value_type, A>::value>::type * = NULL) const {
        std::cout << "a";
    }
    template<class Cont>
    void operator()(const Cont& c, typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<typename Cont::value_type, B>::value>::type * = NULL) const {
        std::cout << "b";
    }
};

int main() {
    std::vector<A> a;
    std::list<B> b;
    C c;
    c(a);
    c(b);
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately I can't use C++11. Futhermore "not very pretty" is one of the greatest euphemism I've ever read ! Thank you though. ;-)

Comment: @matovitch: `is_same` and `enable_if` can be written for C++03 easily.

Comment: @Jarod42 Indeed... I am looking for a prettier solution...but I'm ready to accept this solution if the one from Arkanosis does'nt support set or stack (less anoying in my case).

Comment: @matovitch, boost seems to have those though I haven't tested if they work the same way.

Comment: ok...the predicate template parameter of std::set is the issue. A and B aren't ordered types so I think I am good with it.

Comment: I changed my mind : I will accept this answer. A trick like std::enable_if which allow to specialized over typedef or maybe static member value could be useful in other situations. user2079303 shows the limit of the solution of Arkanosis.